# android numpad keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

how do i make it so that when focus is brought to an input text field in my application that the numpad keyboard with the 9 number keys on them opens rather than the full qwerty keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the input type of your EditText view to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType):

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Or a related type based on your requirements

Comment: actually what i need was android:inputType="phone"

Comment: brings up the 10 key numpad istead of the qwerty keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You must only add this line on your code:

```
input.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);
```

this will show de 12 key keyboard more or less what you want, isn't it?